# Chebychev to get at least 90 %

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Im am given a list of integers and asked to give the interval that contains at least 90 % of my values.

Values : 
$62,56,72,83,66,77,62,71,50,58,
74,81,76,67,70,70,69,67,80,81,
74,53,73,55,66,88,73,61,63,70,
72,63,75,68,78,75,61,69,80,82,
87,57,74,74,85,68,75,63,81,73$

At First, I found the following values :

$ avg = 70.56 $

$ variance = 80.55 $

$ standard deviation = 8.97 $

Now the part I am not sure.
Chebychev inequality is $1 - \frac{1}{k^2}$

k * std var. being how far from the mean  the numbers are.

I figured that with a k of 4, i get $15/16$ which is about $93 %$

**Is that ok or do I have to figure out some fraction of k to get exactly 90 % that is asked ?** How do I figure out precisely that fraction ?

Using a k of 4, I multiplied my std var by 4, and that gives me a minimum of 34.68 and maximum of 106.44

Looking at my numbers, the min and max seems a bit off...

So for now, my answer is : the interval is $[34.68,106.44]$ covers at least 93.75 %

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** [Chebyshev's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) says
$$
\mathrm{P}\left(|X-\mu|\ge k\sigma\right)\le\frac1{k^2}
$$

If we set $\frac1{k^2}=0.10$, that is, $k\doteq3.162$, then at most $10\%$ of the samples would be outside of $3.162$ standard deviations from the mean.

Comment: Thanks, I get new smaller valuesas expected. They still seem a bit off but I understand that's the whole point of it to be large enough to cover 90 %. $70.56 - 3.162*8.97 = 42.20$ low
$70.56 + 3.162*8.97 = 98.92 $ high

Comment: @Dave: those look like the values I got, too. I know the Chebyshev bounds are not very tight, but they are correct and easy to compute.